# Should I be saving my data in a .csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I am writing a small .py file that contains some classes to be imported later repetitively into other work. The mentioned .py file uses some small database (in order of KB) in the form of tables. Do you think it is better to store this data in the same .py file or is it better to keep it in a separate .csv file? What are the differences in terms of performance and convenience for later use? A point that I might have to mention is that this data is **numerical** and is **not prone to any possible change** in the future.
Single items are to be accessed from this data at a time.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give it more focus - it is really not possible to provide a single, objective answer. Any answer currently will be an "it depends" on information the question should clarify. How large is the data? Order of kB, MB, GB, TB, ...? How is the data accessed? Sequentially, randomly, all at once? Is it the bulk of time spent processing the data, or is reading critical for performance? How about parallelism? Does the storage need to be space efficient? Should it be human-readable? Is the data tied strongly to the code, or will different deployments have different data?

Comment: Thank you, I added some answers to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather not hard-code the data into the py file. If you keep it separate the py file is more versatile and easily transferable to other data. A separate file would also make it easier to replace the dataset ("data not prone to change" may mean only that individual values are constant, not the whole set).

The resources required for the import may vary depending on the libraries used and the type of object created (see [here](https://medium.com/casual-inference/the-most-time-efficient-ways-to-import-csv-data-in-python-cc159b44063d) for more details). This however may be negligible, depending on the size of the data.

Consider creating a function that imports the data once, pickles (serializes) it and loads the serialized form (as long as the data is unchanged, or according to user input). This is especially useful for large datasets and some other cases which do not seem to apply to you.

Comment: Thank you very much. In fact, for each call of the .py file, I will only need one specific row of the data set.

Answer (score 1):

If readability of the python class is not a concern (although it's best practice to keep code as readable as possible), the big question here will be 'how much' data are we talking about? If you have gigabytes of data then you don't want to have this all sitting in memory at the same time (i.e. what would happen if you just kept it as a constant in a .py file). Instead, for such large data, you want to read it from disk (maybe as a csv) as and when you need it.

Of course storing it in disk has a performance hit because reading from disk is slower than reading from memory. Whether or not the performance hit is okay for your application is up to you to decide.

A good in-between to ensure readability and good performance might be (assuming you have enough memory) to store the data in a csv, read it all at once on start up and keep it in memory for repeated calls.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is not that big at all, but I guess I prefer not to keep it accessible in the code, because this might have a lot of changes to come.

Answer (score 0):

It's better practice to write into a csv file as it improves readability of the entire code. It won't hurt you performance and will really benefit you.

Comment: Thank you very much. And how to preserve the link between both files? Should I initiate a directory in which to store them together? It would be more like a package I guess??

Comment: It should be stored either in the same directory as the .py file or in some "constant" directory that you will always access. Usually I prefer the first option. btw Remember python provides many tools to work with csv files to make your life easier

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion is to store data in Json format. Like in MongoDb, by adapting No-Sql format. This will help you in easily manage and control over the data.

Comment: Well, can you please name some advantages of using JSON instead of csv? because I guess writing a csv file is a bit easier.